# Using PHP/SQL with while loop for multiple datasets from database

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked around a bit now trying to figure out how to do this, but while some answers are similiar, they don't seem to be exactly what I am trying to do.

I have a reports database where it stores a customer's name and items sold to them on specified dates with dollar amounts.

i.e:

| customer | invdate | model | iclass | qty | price | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | 2023-04-01 | Model 1 | 19 | 3 | 10.00 | 30.00 |
| Customer 1 | 2023-04-10 | Model 2 | 19 | 2 | 5.00 | 10.00 |
| Customer 1 | 2023-04-14 | Model 4 | 21 | 3 | 7.00 | 21.00 |
| Customer 1 | 2023-06-21 | Model 5 | 21 | 2 | 3.00 | 6.00 |
| Customer 2 | 2023-07-01 | Model 1 | 19 | 1 | 10.00 | 10.00 |
| Customer 2 | 2023-08-09 | Model 5 | 21 | 2 | 3.00 | 6.00 |

I need to run a set of queries for each class type grouped together a single row to display on a website for an at a glance view.

I have it working for customer specific data, but if I try to have it display ALL customers, each with their own row, it won't work and I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

Current SQL for class types that is not working:

```
SELECT customer,SUM(qty) AS cat1_qty,SUM(total) AS cat1_total 
FROM reports 
WHERE iclass IN ("19","20","21") 
    AND invdate BETWEEN ? AND ? 
GROUP BY customer 
JOIN 
SELECT customer,SUM(qty) AS cat2_qty,SUM(total) AS cat2_total 
FROM reports 
WHERE iclass IN ("23","30","31") 
    AND invdate BETWEEN ? AND ? 
GROUP BY customer 
JOIN SELECT customer,SUM(qty) AS cat3_qty,SUM(total) AS cat3_total 
FROM reports 
WHERE iclass IN ("45","47") 
    AND invdate BETWEEN ? AND ? 
GROUP BY customer
```

The `iclass` WHERE clause has different class numbers based on type of items in a category (a single category could have multiple classes in it).

I tried using a JOIN to join the separate select statements together, but it keeps giving me a bunch of syntax errors.

For the while loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['customer'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['cat1_total'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['cat1_qty'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['cat2_total'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['cat2_qty'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['cat3_total'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['cat3_qty'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['cat1_total'] + $row['cat2_total'] + $row['cat3_total'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

The headers for above are:

| Customer | Cat1 Total | Cat1 QTY | Cat2 Total | Cat2 QTY | Cat3 Total | Cat3 QTY | Combined Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am at a loss as to how to get the datasets to display properly.

Also, for anyone wondering why I just don't put the category ID to simply the select statement, it is a CSV file that is generated by a third party program that is uploaded into the database that we have no control over the columns, and it doesn't have a category column to reference, just the class columns.

Comment: When you join with a subquery, you have to put the subquery in parentheses.